# Laravel validation: required field in not required array

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

Request can contain field `coord` ({x: 1, y: 2}) or not contain it. For example:

Correct (without `coord`):

```
[
    'another_param' => 'value',
],
```

Correct:

```
[
    'another_param' => 'value',
    'coord' => [
        'x' => 1,
        'y' => 2,
    ],
],
```

Invalid (wrong format of `coord`):

```
[
    'another_param' => 'value',
    'coord' => [
        'x' => 1,
    ],
],
```

Whether it can be written by standard rules (without custom and closures).

My attempt:

```
'rules' => [
    'coord' => 'array',
    'coord.x' => 'required',
    'coord.y' => 'required',
],
```

But if a request don't contain `coord` then Error: The `coord.x` field is required.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`sometimes`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) validation rule so it only applies when the field is present.

```
'rules' => [
    'coord' => 'sometimes|array',
    'coord.x' => 'required',
    'coord.y' => 'required',
],
```

Comment: There is also the `nullable` option that might be needed if the value exists but is null https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields

Comment: No, it's not working for input without "coord": the coord.x is required & the coord.y is required.

Comment: try adding `sometimes|required` to those two also

Comment: Phiter, then empty "coord" will be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's still actual but here's how I solved it:

```
'rules' => [
    'coord' => ['nullable', 'array'],
    'coord.x' => 'required_unless:coord,null',
    'coord.y' => 'required_unless:coord,null',
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can require the fields when the array is provided using required_with:

```
'rules' => [
    'coord' => 'sometimes|array|min:1',
    'coord.x' => 'required_with:coord',
    'coord.y' => 'required_with:coord',
],
```

The `sometimes` rule allows this field to be discarded and `min:1` ensures when this coord field is provided, it's not an empty array.

Comment: 1. empty coord will be valid. 2. if I have 10 field I must write these all for each?

Comment: You could use nullable or sometimes on the coord itself.  Just  required_with:coord may work on all of the fields, haven't tried it

Comment: maybe, but it more ugly then write custom closure for validation

Comment: why is it more ugly?  it's only a few more characters than required.

Comment: ugliness is not measured by the number of characters :)

Comment: ok... well it's pretty descriptive to me, when providing coord, you need x and y,  not sure what defines ugly in your book but this is pretty readable to me.

Answer (score -1):

You can try validating the array fields as `coord.*.x`
I mean:

```
'rules' => [
    'coord' => 'array',
    'coord.*.x' => 'required',
    'coord.*.y' => 'required',
],
```

Then if coord array has an element, x and y will be required

Comment: This would be valid for case, when coord is an actual array of x,y tuples, but it only contains x and y directly as elements.